# Spring CrudRepository cannot share generated id in composite primary key

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, composite-primary-key, spring-repositories

I'm trying use *spring CRUDRepository* for inserting new object into database using JPA database model (**User.java**, **UserInfo.java**). Database model are related with composite primary key (**UserPK.java**), where one of them is automatic generated (field named **id**) and second (field named **type**) is set in beginning.

And I get errors when I create new object with using *CRUDRepository* (**UserRepository.java**) - cannot insert new object into second model (**UserInfo.java**), because **id** is null (first model was added correctly). I think problem is in sharing/mapping composite primary key in database model. 
I tried the same model with *EntityManager* and it wasn't error - all was added. Next I used *@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns* annotation, but with that same result as above (but there I'm not sure that I used it correctly) - *CRUDRepository* failed and *EntityManager* success.

Can anyone help me find solution? I add also source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/kaczla/SpringBootCompositePrimaryKey) if someone wants to run code.

**Logs below:**

Log *CRUDRepository*

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_1_, user0_.type as type2_0_1_, user0_.email as email3_0_1_, user0_.login as login4_0_1_, userinfo1_.id as id3_1_0_, userinfo1_.type as type4_1_0_, userinfo1_.name as name1_1_0_, userinfo1_.surname as surname2_1_0_ from user user0_ left outer join user_info userinfo1_ on user0_.id=userinfo1_.id and user0_.type=userinfo1_.type where user0_.id=? and user0_.type=?
Hibernate: call next value for seq_id
Hibernate: select userinfo0_.id as id3_1_0_, userinfo0_.type as type4_1_0_, userinfo0_.name as name1_1_0_, userinfo0_.surname as surname2_1_0_ from user_info userinfo0_ where userinfo0_.id=? and userinfo0_.type=?
Hibernate: insert into user (email, login, id, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user_info (name, surname, id, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
 WARN 17653 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502
ERROR 17653 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into user_info (name, surname, id, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-196]
...
```

Log *EntityManager*

```
Hibernate: call next value for seq_id
Hibernate: insert into user (email, login, id, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user_info (name, surname, id, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**Code below:**

Main model: **User.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@IdClass(UserPK.class)
public class User implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private UserInfo info;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ID", sequenceName = "SEQ_ID", allocationSize = 1)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private String type;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "LOGIN")
    private String login;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    /* ... */
}
```

Second model: **UserInfo.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_INFO")
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
     @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
     @JoinColumn(name = "type", referencedColumnName = "type")
    })
    @JsonBackReference
    @MapsId
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "SURNAME")
    private String surname;
    /* ... */
}
```

Composed primary key: **UserPK.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserPK implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String type;
    /* ... */
}
```

*spring CRUDRepository*: **UserRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UserPK> {
    User findByIdAndAndType(Long id, String type);
}
```

Repository using *EntityManager*: **UserRepositoryEM.java**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserRepositoryEM {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public User findByKey(UserPK key) {
        return entityManager.find(User.class, key);
    }

    public User save(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.flush();
        return user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `User` and `UserPK` classes need slight modification. Your field to column mappings for the primary key should be inside the `UserPK` class. Here are the changes,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private UserInfo info;

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserPK id;

    @Column(name = "LOGIN", nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false)
    private String email;
    /* ... */

    @Embeddable
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ID",  initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
    public static class UserPK implements Serializable {

        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_ID")
        @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "TYPE", nullable = false)
        private String type;
    }
}
```

Corresponding changes to the repository,

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, User.UserPK> {
    User findByIdAndAndType(Long id, String type);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I change code as you say: **UserPK.java**, **User.java** + **UserRepository.java**. You can look changes on [GitHub](https://github.com/kaczla/SpringBootCompositePrimaryKey/tree/embeddedid). Now it is other problem, cannot generate key - even I set key, it cannot be share to **UserInfo.java**

Comment: Made some modification to UserPK class wrt sequence generator. Try it now.

Comment: I changed **UserPK.java** but it didn't help. Looking at logs, hibernate didn't create sequencer for **UserPK.java**, so automatic generated id cannot be with @Embeddable annotation or we doing something wrong.
On the other hand I resolve problem with sharing/mapping composite primary key - I just added *@EmbeddedId* annotation in **UserInfo.java**. Of course you can see changes in [GitHub](https://github.com/kaczla/SpringBootCompositePrimaryKey/tree/embeddedid)